# Skipping modal window from HttpErrorHandle in AuthInterceptor

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors

I have HttpErrorInterceptor and AuthInterceptor. Both of them are handling error code 400. The problem occurs while I'm trying to refresh the jwt token and the backend throws a bad request because either the refresh token has expired or it's invalid. In case that bad request happens on `/api/token/refresh`, I just want to log out the user and **suppress all errors**. I added an additional header which is supposed to skip the error modal window in HttpErrorInterceptor but the problem is that the actual error happens before the skip code and in the end that annoying modal window message appears.

If you look at the image below, you will see that `this.authService.logout()` was executed and right after it the `HTTP Interceptor Skip` (from HttpErrorInterceptor) and the actual error was displayed above them.

[image]

How can I suppress all error messages for `/api/token/refresh` (`this.authService.refreshToken()`), so when it fails, it wouldn't pop that modal window up with error code 400?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dziwbx

Comment: In which order do you provide the interceptors?

Comment: ```{ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptor, multi: true },
  { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: HttpErrorInterceptor, multi: true }```

Comment: When I change their order - https://i.imgur.com/sXa8FGX.png. The skipping code never executes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it with `HttpBackend`. It basically bypasses the interceptors.

```
import { HttpClient, ..., HttpBackend } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class TestService {

  private httpClient: HttpClient;

  constructor( handler: HttpBackend) { 
     this.httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
  }
....
```

Comment: If there is a better solution, please comment/answer it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I find it hard to exactly tell what the problem is(as I don't know how Angular handles this behind the scenes), but I think it boils down to how a stream that emits errors can be handled.

```js
const obsErr$ = throwError('err');

function intercept (src) {  
  return src
    .pipe(
      catchError(v => {
        return of('err caught in int1: ' + v);
      })
    )
}

function intercept2 (src) {
  return src
    .pipe(
      catchError(v => {
        return of('err caught in int2: ' + v);
      })
    )
}
```

#### Case 1

```js
obsErr$
  .pipe(
    intercept,
    intercept2,
  )
  .subscribe(console.log) // err caught in int1: err
```

The error will be caught only **once**, in the first interceptor.

#### Case 2

```js
obsErr$.pipe(intercept)
  .subscribe(v => console.log('i1', v))

obsErr$.pipe(intercept2)
  .subscribe(v => console.log('i2', v))
```

Here, the each interceptor will have its own source and also its own error to catch.

I hope this is helpful in some way.

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/catching-errors?file=index.ts).

Comment: It doesn't really solve it. I want my logic split into two interceptors